# Enum of strings not printing expected value

Tags: d, dmd

I have the following D program:

```
import std.stdio;

enum XYZ : string
{
    A = "hello",
    B = "foo",
    C = "bar"
}

void main()
{
    writeln(XYZ.A);
    writeln(XYZ.B);
    writeln(XYZ.C);
}
```

That prints:

> A
>
> B
>
> C

I would expect it to print `hello`, `foo`, and `bar`. Why is the program printing the *name* of the constant instead of its *value*? And how to print the string value then?

Compiler is DMD v2.063.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why is the program printing the name of the constant instead of its value?

As a general rule, `writeln` and other functions print the names of enum values, since for e.g. numeric types the name conveys more information than a number.

> And how to print the string value then?

Just cast it to a string:

```
cast(string)XYZ.A
```